# Regex to capture spaces AND commas?

Tags: regex

I love [this tool](http://www.regexr.com/), but regex is still so cryptic:

To capture first space:

```
( )
```

To capture first comma:

```
(,)
```

How can I capture all occurrences of spaces and commas?

Here is an example string:

```
"1 2,3 4,5 6,7"
```

Comment: Can we ask **why** you want to **capture** spaces and commas? Maybe we can think of an easier way to accomplish you end purpose.

Comment: I'm trying (terribly) to parse an input file in a new environment (Qt Creator).  The input file holds a weighted adjacency list representation of an undirected graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to do this.

```
([ ,]+)
```

**Explanation**:

```
(          # group and capture to \1:
  [ ,]+    #   any character of: ' ', ',' (1 or more times)
)          # end of \1
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yT2bO2)

Comment: I'm not seeing that highlight anything on the test string in http://www.regexr.com/.  I'll try in code.

Comment: ok, that freakin worked like magic in code.  I don't think I had parens around the brackets.

Comment: @tarabyte if this solved your problem, mark it as correct so we know that we don't have to keep working on it.